# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    ArrayData inputData = getArrayDataFromImage(args[0]);
    int minContrast = (args.length >= 4) ? 64 : Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
    ArrayData outputData = houghTransform(inputData, Integer.parseInt(args[2]), Integer.parseInt(args[3]), minContrast);
    writeOutputImage(args[1], outputData);
    return;
  }
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at HoughTransform.main(HoughTransform.java:136)
```

Comment: print the arraysize and check whether you are passing the appropriate values or not

Comment: what is the content in args[]

Comment: Look like you do not give 4 arguments to yout program.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running your program with any command line arguments, so the array is empty.

```
ArrayData inputData = getArrayDataFromImage(
    args.length < 1 ? "some-default-file" : args[0]
);
```

Or, (if you dislike the conditional operator `? :` - aka the ternary)

```
ArrayData inputData = null;
if (args.length < 1) {
    inputData = getArrayDataFromImage("some-default-file");
} else {
    inputData = getArrayDataFromImage(args[0]);
}
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMb0UtamFDT184SmM     This is my whole program if you can take a look, i can't figure it out. Thank you

Comment: @PogorDorin The error is in how you are **running** the program (note that my answer tells you how to prevent that error). `java -jar myfile.jar ARG0 ARG1 ARG2`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Exception in this line

```
 ArrayData inputData = getArrayDataFromImage(args[0]);
```

because you are not passing any argument from the command Line so the length of String Array `[] args` is **0** and you are trying to access the first element .

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

This exception is thrown to indicate that an **array** has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either `negative` or `greater` than or `equal` to the size of the array.